# Execute code after loading the iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building an weather app. I have a function getAllData:

```
- (void)getAllData {
    self.tempNowData = [self.getTempLibrary getTempNowData];
    self.iconNowData = [self.getTempLibrary getIconNowData];

    self.tempPlus3Data = [self.getTempLibrary getTempPlus3Data];
    self.iconPlus3Data = [self.getTempLibrary getIconPlus3Data];

    self.tempPlus6Data = [self.getTempLibrary getTempPlus6Data];
    self.iconPlus6Data = [self.getTempLibrary getIconPlus6Data];

    self.tempPlus9Data = [self.getTempLibrary getTempPlus9Data];
    self.iconPlus9Data = [self.getTempLibrary getIconPlus9Data];

    self.tempPlus12Data = [self.getTempLibrary getTempPlus12Data];
    self.iconPlus12Data = [self.getTempLibrary getIconPlus12Data];

    self.tempPlus15Data = [self.getTempLibrary getTempPlus15Data];
    self.iconPlus15Data = [self.getTempLibrary getIconPlus15Data];

    self.tempPlus24Data = [self.getTempLibrary getTempPlus24Data];
    self.iconPlus24Data = [self.getTempLibrary getIconPlus24Data];

    self.cityData  = [self.getTempLibrary city];
}
```

It calls getTempLibrary class which takes and parse JSON and gives the data.

There is also the function setAllData (unfinished, just setting one value):

```
- (void)setAllData {
    self.tempNow.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@°C", self.tempNowData];
}
```

When I call this function with button everything works good.

```
- (IBAction)refreshButton:(id)sender {

    [self getAllData];
    [self setAllData];
}
```

When I put the same code to viewDidLoad, it shows temperature for latitude 0 and longitude 0. I check GPS location in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.getTempLibrary = [[GetTemp alloc] init];
    [self.getTempLibrary getCurrentLocation];
    [self getAllData];
    [self setAllData];

}
```

I thought it's too early to take a GPS location but when I call functions by button, it works (show up right temperature).

Comment: Sorry, I added the code.

Comment: Show your `viewDidLoad` method (the one that isn't working as expected). And define "doesn't work at all". What happens? Compiler error? Linker error? Runtime error? Something doesn't populate correctly or at all? If you want help, you need to provide details.

Comment: Edited again. I'm really sorry.

Comment: You still haven't told us what the problem is. You say when the code is called from the button, "it works". What works? What "doesn't work" when you call the code from `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I don't even get the question :) GPS is async in any case so you can't really check in viewDidLoad

Comment: If you are using CLLocationManager you'll need to wait until it calls the delegate function `didUpdateLocation`

Comment: I call getCurrentLocation in viewDidLoad to get GPS coordinates. Then I ask API with latitude and longitude for weather (temperature). I want to get temperature immediately after starting my app so I call getAllData to get data from API and setAllData to set label's text. 
When I run my app, I get wrong temperature. It's correct when I click "Refresh" (Refresh called it again).

Answer (score 0):

Dont do like this. Use *NSOperationQueue* instead.

Create *NSOperation*(s) for TempNow,TempPlus, etc. Add these operations in the queue and let it download asynchronously for you. Your method needs to be generalised by the way :)

PS: If there is no dependency between TempNow, TempPlus, etc., you can use *GCD* instead.